# Convert a unicode string to characters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following string:

```
l\u0092issue
```

My question is how to convert it to utf8 characters ?

I have tried that

```
1.9.3p484 :024 > "l\u0092issue".encode('utf-8')
 => "l\u0092issue"
```

Answer (score 16):

You seem to have got your encodings into a bit of a mix up. If you haven’t already, you should first read [Joel Spolsky’s article *The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) which provides a good introduction into this type of thing. There is a good set of articles on how Ruby handles character encodings at http://graysoftinc.com/character-encodings/understanding-m17n-multilingualization. You could also have a look at the Ruby docs for [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html) and [Encoding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Encoding.html).

In this specific case, the string `l\u0092issue` means that the second character is the character with the unicode codepoint 0x92. This codepoint is `PRIVATE USE TWO` (see the [chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf)), which basically means this position isn’t used.

However, looking at the [Windows CP-1252 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), position 0x92 is occupied by the character `’`, so if this is the missing character the the string would be `l’issue`, whick looks a lot more likely even though I don’t speak French.

What I suspect has happened is your program has received the string `l’issue` encoded in CP-1252, but has assumed it was encoded in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (ISO-8859-1 and CP-1252 are quite closely related) and re-encoded it to UTF-8 leaving you with the string you now have.

The *real* fix for you is to be careful about the encodings of any strings that enter (and leave) your program, and how you manage them.

To transform your string to `l’issue`, you can [`encode`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-encode) it back to `ISO-8859-1`, then use [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) to tell Ruby the *real* encoding of CP-1252, and then you can re-encode to UTF-8:

```
2.1.0 :001 > s = "l\u0092issue"
 => "l\u0092issue" 
2.1.0 :002 > s = s.encode('iso-8859-1')
 => "l\x92issue" 
2.1.0 :003 > s.force_encoding('cp1252')
 => "l\x92issue" 
2.1.0 :004 > s.encode('utf-8')
 => "l’issue"
```

This is only really a demonstration of what is going on though. The real solution is to make sure you’re handling encodings correctly.

Comment: this really helped me out.I had the exact problem with \u0092..thanks..you are awesome!

Comment: To make this print in IRB, you have to encode, force encoding, then re-encode. This wasn't clear to me from the answer. `"l\u0092issue".encode('iso-8859-1').force_encoding('cp1252').encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 4):

That *is* encoded as UTF-8 (unless you changed the original string encoding). Ruby is just showing you the escape sequences when you `inspect` the string (which is why IRB does there). `\u0092` is the escape sequence for [this character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm).

Try `puts "l\u0092issue"` to see the rendered character, if your terminal font supports it.

Comment: This did not work for me. `"l\u0092issue".encode('iso-8859-1').force_encoding('cp1252').encode('utf-8')` displays the correct character, but `puts "l\u0092issue"` does not.